# Triangles meets in the middle

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to cover the bottom part of div with triangles so they meet and still get that point in the middle. Check image

[image]
Or maybe cut out that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 86%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 86%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
```

[My result](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwhjpp0c/1/).